# Complicated constant in "The Software Equation"?

Tags: project-management, estimation

Why are the constants in [The Software Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_equation) so complicated?

Here is the equation.

[image: Software Equation]

where

E = Project effort measured in person-months or person-years

LOC =Lines of Code estimate for the project

t= Length of project measured in months or years

B= "special skills factor"

P= "Productivity Parameter"

Values of B and P are given for particular cases in two tables in the wikipedia page.

Since B and P are constant for particular cases we could take the constants out of the cube and define new constants that do not have complicated exponents. That would really make the equation simple.

It seems to me that these constants are vague and does not correspond to reality as much as LOC or length of project does.

If they do not have some physical meaning than why not use constants that make the equation look simple?

Comment: The paper you are looking for is Software Engineering Economics by Barry Boehm.  It was published in 1981.

Answer (score 4):

If it fits, it works.

Quite simply, the people who came up with the first version of the equation took a whole bunch of projects and looked at how much effort (in terms of man months or years) was put into the project, and how much time it took to produce the product.  And then they fit it to a curve, and thats the numbers that came out of the data.

From the [COCOMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOMO) page, it appears that this was based on 63 projects at TRW Aerospace where Bohm was a director and looked at projects in the 2-10 kSLOC.

> [image: Effort vs Size]

The above is a plot from [Improving Software Productivity](http://csse.usc.edu/TECHRPTS/1987/usccse87-502/usccse87-502.pdf) by Boehm showing the difference between Cobol and 4GL languages (back in the 1980s context of 4GL) to see if there were productivity gains.  While its not shown there, you could draw a line to fit it.

Since then other attempts at refining COCOMO to take into account the different types of projects (small teams with deep domain experience and less right requirements are different than tight requirements and righted constraints).  These have been various values to tweak - how familiar are you with the environment? is the process mature? etc...

But thats all that it really is - take a bunch of numbers, see what line fits them best and publish that.

Comment: I get that they took some data and than plotted in graph and than tried fit a equation. Effort, LOC and Time for the project can be taken as data from real projects. Now that leaves us with the two constants B and P. What I dont get is why did they have to make it so complicated. It would make sense if those constants had some real physical meaning.

Comment: @IbraheemMoosa look at the [15 parameters in COCOMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOMO#Intermediate_COCOMOs) - there are constant value ranges all over the place (and not even the same range). They are items that people who have looked at projects believe to have found play a role and (in theory) give a better predictor of the outcome.  The values are not constants - they are adjustments that try to take into additional attributes of the projects.

Comment: I guess these parameters are used in other equations and simplifying just one equation was not worth it.